# Goutte / Web Scraping - How to intercept and download a file

Tags: web-scraping, goutte

Firstly, thanks in advance for your help here, it's really appreciated!

I've successfully managed to get Goutte to authenticate, hit a URL, change a select field and click a submit button.

The page then reloads and as it finishes loading, it downloads a file to the client.

How do I intercept this file within Goutte? I've read as much doco as I can but can't seem to find an answer. I then want to basically hit this file, traverse it and save it locally.

Depending upon the file type, I want to traverse it, or save it locally.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to achieve this. In my situation, I open the URL where the file is (after authentication) then the server gives the file (as an object of Page), afterwards you can get the content of the page.

```
// $url contains the path to the file.
$session->visit($url);
$page = $session->getPage();
$saved = file_put_contents($targetFilePath, $page->getContent());
```

In my case, I am downloading zip file. In your case, probably save it in a temporary location, detect the type then move it to any desired directory.
Hope this helps.